# Is it possible to programmatically open an app on an iOS device based on a trigger from a web api

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to use an old iPad to view an ip camera feed. Instead of keeping the iPad on all day, I want to be able to tell the iPad to wake and open the camera viewer application when the camera senses motion. (Not just a small notification on lock screen, I want to be able to view a full screen image of the cameras feed). After a given period of time the iPad would go back to an off/sleep mode. Is this even possible in iOS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the "Singe App Mode" and "Background Execution". Choose an event type that can take your device out from background mode, like VOIP. Do not expect the app to be accepted in the public app store.